# In CompoundJS how does database seeding work?

Tags: compoundjs, railway.js

I see that there is a folder for database seeds and a command for it but I couldn't find any documentation on how it works.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this is a little late for an answer, but if you haven't found one yet, here goes.

To create seeds:

```
railway seed harvest
```

The keyword `harvest` will invoke the railway app so that it creates seeds based on whatever you currently have in the database. As for where this goes, depending on what environment you have set, eg development, production, etc, it will place you seed files like so:

```
root/db/seeds/[environment]/[model].coffee
```

...where [model] is your model (User, Post, Account, etc), and [environment] is your environment (development, test, production, etc).

To seed the database:

```
railway seed
```

The documentation is a little light on seeding right now.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question and the RailwayJS framework is now called [CompoundJS](https://github.com/1602/compound) but Johnny's advice still works.  For anyone looking for a bit more detail this might help.

**db/schema.js**

```
var Country = describe('Country', function () {
    property('name', String);
    set('restPath', pathTo.countries);
});
```

**db/seeds/development/country.js**

```
console.log('Seeding countries...');

var countries = [{
    name: 'Canada'
}, {
    name: 'USA'
}];

countries.forEach(function(obj) {
    Country.create(obj, function(country) {
        console.log('Added: ', country);
    });  
});
```

Then run:

```
$ compound seed
Seeding countries...
Added: { name: 'Canada', id: 1 }
Added: { name: 'USA', id: 2 }
```

Comment: When I run this example, the compound seeding seems to hang... if I kill the seeding, I can see this data in the Mongo database, but killing the seeding just seems weird... any ideas?

Comment: Also, if I made this into a corresponding CoffeeScript file, I get no hanging... this is what that script would look like: `Country.seed ->
  name: 'USA'

Country.seed ->
  name: 'Canada'`.  Unfortunately, my use case requires using the JavaScript approach... I've tried converting my JS into a CS file, but no dice.

Comment: Also, in your `Country.create` callback, it should be `function(err, country)`.